# Count dicts which has same value

Tags: python, dictionary

I did count dicts which has same value and tried to add result into dict. But the problem is I couldn't remove the duplicated dicts.

```
from collections import defaultdict

[
  {"project_name": "apollo"}, 
  {"project_name": "apollo"}
]
```

for example there are two apollo projects in the `list`. So I am trying to merge the dicts that has same value. And add the counted result as new key value pair.

expected output be like.

```
[
  {
    "project_name": "apollo", 
    "count": "2"
  }
]
```

I tried something like below.

```
d = defaultdict(int)
for item in conversions:
    key = item['project_name']
    d[key] += 1
    dic["count"] = d[key]
```

But the result is (of course) came out like below.

```
[
  {"project_name": "apollo", "count": "1"},
  {"project_name": "apollo", "count": "2"}
]
```

How to manage to count the quantity dicts and merge.

Comment: You mention "same value"...but the key is the same, so should `[{"foo": "bar"}, {"baz": "bar"}]` yield a result count of 2 and be grouped together? If so, how should they be formatted?

Comment: actually, I did mentioned about the expected output in the question. and yes both dicts has same key value pair. @ggorlen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Slightly changed your code and restructured the result:

```
from collections import defaultdict


conversions = [
  {"project_name": "apollo"}, 
  {"project_name": "apollo"},
  {"project_name": "foo"},
  {"project_name": "apollo"}
]

d = defaultdict(int)

for item in conversions:
    key = item['project_name']
    d[key] += 1

res = [{"project_name": k, "count": v} for (k, v) in d.items()]
print(res)
```

Output:

```
[{'count': 3, 'project_name': 'apollo'}, {'count': 1, 'project_name': 'foo'}]
```

Comment: it's the expected results, thank you for the touch. helped a lot. but inside the  `res` var is a mistery to me :)

Comment: It's called List Comprehension - Google shows you a lot of tutorials about it :)